# Solution for $\frac{8(9^n)}{8(9^n)+2(4^n)} \gt 0.99$

Tags: inequality

I'm currently trying to come up with a solution for $\frac{8(9^n)}{8(9^n)+2(4^n)} \gt 0.99$

I don't understand how i could evaluate the n within to find the exact value of n at all, and would appreciate a solution.
Note: I came up with the above question myself, so i understand that it may be very difficult or impossible to answer it aswell.

Comment: Hint: divide the fraction through by $9^n$.

Comment: Already tried that. Got stuck trying to figure out what to do with the other $4^n$

Comment: Multiply by $100$ so that all inequality becomes integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{8(9^n)}{8(9^n)+2(4^n)}>0.99\iff$

$8(9^n)>0.99(8(9^n)+2(4^n))\iff$

$8(9^n)>0.99(8(9^n))+0.99(2(4^n))\iff$

$0.01(8(9^n))>0.99(2(4^n))\iff$

$1(8(9^n))>99(2(4^n))\iff$

$8(9^n)>198(4^n)\iff$

$4(9^n)>99(4^n)\iff$

$9^n>99(4^{n-1})\iff$

$9^{n-1}>11(4^{n-1})\iff$

$\frac{9^{n-1}}{4^{n-1}}>11\iff$

$\left(\frac{9}{4}\right)^{n-1}>11\iff$

$n-1>\log_{9/4}11\iff$

$n-1>2.957\dots\iff$

$n>3.957\dots\implies$

$n\geq4$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$\frac{8(9^n)}{8(9^n)+2(4^n)} \gt 0.99 \implies \frac{8(9^n)+2(4^n)}{8(9^n)} \lt \frac 1 {0.99}$$ that is to say $$1+\frac 14 \Big(\frac 49\Big)^n\lt \frac 1 {0.99}$$ then $$\Big(\frac 49\Big)^n\lt \frac 4{99}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{8(9^n)}{8(9^n)+2(4^n)} \gt 0.99$$

$$100(8(9^n)) > 99(8(9^n)+2(4^n))$$

$$8(9^n) > 198(4^n)$$

$$\Big(\frac{4}{9}\Big)^n < \frac{8}{198} = \frac{4}{9}\frac{1}{11}$$

$$\Big(\frac{4}{9}\Big)^{n-1} < \frac{1}{11}$$

$$n-1 > log_{\frac{4}{9}}{\frac{1}{11}} \approx 2.96$$

Therefore $n \geq 4$.